# Prevent this variable from changing

Tags: ruby

I am doing a word problem. I am trying to set two arrays. One serves as a benchmark (doesn't change during iteration), the other changes during iteration. Here is an example:

```
seed = 1
a = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
bm = a[seed]
a[seed].each.with_index do |x, i|
  if bm.include?(0)
    a[seed][i] = "WRONG"
  else
    a[seed][i] = 0 unless i == 3
  end
end

a #         => [[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, "WRONG", "WRONG, "WRONG"], [1, 1]]
# Should be => [[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1]]
bm #        => [0, "WRONG", "WRONG, "WRONG"]
# Should be => [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Usually if you want to have a "before and after" in your code you can do:

```
a = 5
b = a
a = 6
a # => 6
b # => 5
```

In this case, it doesn't change `b` when `a` is changed. Why does this happen? I suspect it's because the second example is storing the number as `b` whereas in the first example, it's storing the code only. What can I do to fix this? Is this bad practice?

Comment: I would recommend editing your title to include something about "objects changing" rather than variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.  When you assign the array to `bm` you're really assigning a reference (or pointer, not sure what Ruby prefers to call it) to `a[seed]`. You can see this by printing out the `object_id` of both variables:

```
> a[seed].object_id
=> 70347648205960
> bm.object_id
=> 70347648205960
```

Note that they are pointing to the same internal object.  The solution is to use `dup` to duplicate the array and assign the new one to `bm2`.

```
> bm2 = a[seed].dup
=> [1, 1, 1, 1]
> bm2.object_id
=> 70347649948520
```

Note the object_id has changed. And now if I make a change...

```
> a[seed][0] = 'WRONG'
=> "WRONG"
> a[seed]
=> ["WRONG", 1, 1, 1]
> bm
=> ["WRONG", 1, 1, 1]
> bm2
=> [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You might want to Google to read about `object_id`, `dup`, and also `clone` which is similar to dup, but has some differences.